# Modernizr.load not working properly in IE8

Tags: javascript, modernizr, yepnope

I'm trying to load in a specific CSS stylesheet depending whether certain CSS3 features aren't supported in that browser.

The JS code I use is this:

```
// Modernizr feature tests
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.borderradius,
    nope: '/assets/css/border-radius.css'
});
```

In IE8 this gives, according to the developer tools:

```
<link href="undefined" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in Modernizr Minifier. I've encountered the same issue, but was able to fix that manually. Here are the details: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/308